# R: Find groups of vectors that have a > 80% overlap in their elements

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors and I want to identify groups of vectors that share > 80% of their values. I would like the new groups to be named using the names of all the vectors included in the groups. And I want the new elements of the groups to be all possible elements from the grouped vectors. I am not sure how feasible this is.

Here is a simple example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
c <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16)
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
e <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
f <- c(18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26)
g <- c(18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)
h <- c(18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
i <- c(18,19,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

So I think we would get two groups:

```
a-b-c-d-e-i
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
f-g-h
[1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

The values in the vectors do not have to be numeric, they could be strings. Let me know if there is anything else that I would need to specify. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the vectors are in a list V shown in the Note at the end of this answer, calculate an adjacency matrix `adj` such that `adj[i,j]` is 1 if the ith and jth vector have at least 80% of their elements in common and 0 otherwise.  We base this on the fraction of the shorter of the two vectors.  Then use the igraph package to convert `adj` to a graph `g` and compute its components.

```
library(igraph)

overlap <- function(u, v) length(intersect(u, v)) / min(length(u), length(v)) > 0.8
adj <- sapply(V, function(u) sapply(V, overlap, u)) + 0
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj)
memb <- components(g)$membership
memb
## a b c d e f g h i 
## 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 

s <- split(V, memb)
groups <- lapply(s, function(x) unique(unlist(x)))
names(groups) <- lapply(s, function(x) paste(names(x), collapse = "-"))
groups
```

giving:

```
$`a-b-c-d-e-i`
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

$`f-g-h`
[1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

We can also plot the graph:

```
plot(g)
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:**

```
V <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14), b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), 
    c = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16), 
    d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
    16, 17), e = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), f = c(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
    23, 24, 25, 26), g = c(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), h = c(18, 
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), i = c(18, 19, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"
))
```

Comment: That seems to work well to do the grouping of the vectors! I had also asked about having the new groups to named using the names of all the vectors included in the groups (i.e a-b-c-d-e-i and f-g-h), how could we do this?

Comment: Have added that.

Comment: Thanks! In addition, I mentioned that I was looking to get new vectors representing each group, where the elements would be all possible elements from the vectors making up the groups. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh that is also included in the code that you just added right?

Comment: It's awesome by the way, the plots are a nice addition