# How to use functional-style programming in R when the list of inputs depends upon one another?

Tags: r, functional-programming, apply, purrr, do.call

I have a data frame organized like so:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1),
                 startDate = c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-23", "1990-01-30"),
                 endDate = c("1990-01-24", "1990-01-25", "1990-01-31"))
```

Each row represents the start date and end date. There is some overlap in the data though I'd like to identify. For example, the first range of dates goes from January 1, 1990 to January 24, 1990, and then the second row of dates goes from January 23rd, 1990 to January 24th, 1990.

What I want to is create a new data frame which would something like this...
(illustrating by creating a new R dataframe).

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1),
                 startDate = c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-23", "1990-01-30"),
                 endDate = c("1990-01-24", "1990-01-25", "1990-01-31"),
                 overlap = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                 newStartDate = c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1990-01-30"),
                 newEndDate = c("1990-01-25", "1990-01-25", "1990-01-31"))
```

So first, identify every row which overlaps with another row. And then create new columns (newStartDate, newEndDate) which would take the earliest start date and the latest end date from all the overlapping dates.

I already have in my mind how this would work using pseudo code. However, I wonder if there was a way to make this work using "R" style programming, using vectors, and functions and all that. I'm having trouble conceptualizing of how it would work because there are lots of variables you would need to keep track of and what not, and I'm not sure how you could achieve it using things like map, apply, etc.

Hopefully my question is clear!

Comment: Have a look at `foverlaps` function in `data.table` package https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/foverlaps

Answer (score 1):

Below are some alternative approaches.

(1) and (1a) only use Base R.  These are the same except that (1) uses an adjacency matrix and (1a) uses a neighborhood list to avoid forming the potentially large adjacency matrix.

(2) is an SQL solution using the sqldf package.

(3) uses the igraph package and may give a different answer than the above alternatives altlhough in the case of the example in the question the answers are the same.  (3a) is like (3) but like (1a) avoids forming the adjacency matrix.

At the end we provide some graphics.

### Alternatives

**1) Base R** First we convert the dates to `Date` class giving `df2`.  Then we define a function `betw` which checks whether its first argument is between the second and third and use that to define a function `overlap` which given two row indexes into `df2` determines whether they overlap (TRUE) or not (FALSE).

If `V` is the sequence from 1 to the number of rows in `df2` then we can form an adjacency matrix `adj` such that `adj[i,j]` is 1 if rows i and j overlap.  Using that it is straight forward to compute the `overlap`, `newStartDate` and `newEndDate` columns.

This approach uses no packages.

```
df2 <- transform(df, startDate = as.Date(startDate), endDate = as.Date(endDate))

betw <- function(x, a, b) x >= a & x <= b
overlap <- function(i, j) {
  betw(df2[i, "startDate"], df2[j, "startDate"], df2[j, "endDate"]) ||
  betw(df2[j, "startDate"], df2[i, "startDate"], df2[i, "endDate"])
}

# form adjacency matrix of graph having vertices V
V <- 1:nrow(df2)
adj <- sapply(V, function(u) sapply(V, overlap, u)) + 0

orig <- "1970-01-01"
transform(df2, overlap = colSums(adj) > 1,
  newStartDate = as.Date(apply(adj, 1, function(ix) min(startDate[ix == 1])), orig),
  newEndDate = as.Date(apply(adj, 1, function(ix) max(endDate[ix == 1])), orig))
```

giving:

```
  id  startDate    endDate overlap newStartDate newEndDate
1  1 1990-01-01 1990-01-24    TRUE   1990-01-01 1990-01-25
2  1 1990-01-23 1990-01-25    TRUE   1990-01-01 1990-01-25
3  1 1990-01-30 1990-01-31   FALSE   1990-01-30 1990-01-31
```

**1a)** A variation of (1) which avoids forming the `adj` adjacency matrix is to create a neighors list such that `nbrs[[i]]` is a vector of the row numbers that row i overlaps.

```
nbrs <- lapply(1:nr, function(j) Filter(function(i) overlap(i, j), 1:nr))
names(nbrs) <- 1:nr

orig <- "1970-01-01"
transform(df2, overlap = lengths(nbrs) > 1,
  newStartDate = as.Date(sapply(nbrs, function(ix) min(startDate[ix])), orig),
  newEndDate = as.Date(sapply(nbrs, function(ix) max(endDate[ix])), orig))
```

**2) sqldf** Using `df2` we can use SQL to compute the desired output in a single SQL statement:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select 
    a.id, 
    a.startDate as startDate__Date,
    a.endDate as endDate__Date,
    count(b.rowid) > 1 as overlap__logical, 
    min(b.startDate) as newStartDate__Date,
    max(b.endDate) as newEndDate__Date
  from df2 as a
  left join df2 as b on (a.startDate between b.startDate and b.endDate) or
                        (b.startDate between a.startDate and a.endDate)
  group by a.rowid
  order by a.rowid", method = "name__class")
```

giving:

```
  id  startDate    endDate overlap newStartDate newEndDate
1  1 1990-01-01 1990-01-24    TRUE   1990-01-01 1990-01-25
2  1 1990-01-23 1990-01-25    TRUE   1990-01-01 1990-01-25
3  1 1990-01-30 1990-01-31   FALSE   1990-01-30 1990-01-31
```

**3) igraph** Another approach which is not equivalent to (1) or (2) but may be preferred is to partition the rows into connected components using a transitive completion of the overlap relation.  It is similar to this question here: [R: Find groups of vectors that have a > 80% overlap in their elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372430/r-find-groups-of-vectors-that-have-a-80-overlap-in-their-elements)

Using `adj` from (1) form a graph `g` using the igraph package.  Then rows that have no other rows in their connected component are not overlapped.  If we number the connected components 1, 2, ... then `memb` is such that `memb[i]` is the number of the connected component containing row i so for each row we can find the minimum and maximum date over the connected component it belongs to.  Although this gives the same answer as (1) for the input in the question, in general, this is different than (1) because, for example, if rows i and j do not overlap but do each overlap row k then i, j and k are all in the same connected component for purposes of computing the columns of the output.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj, mode = "undirected", diag = FALSE)
memb <- components(g)$membership

# assemble desired output data frame
transform(df2, 
  overlap = ave(memb, memb, FUN = length) > 1,
  newStartDate = ave(startDate, memb, FUN = min),
  newEndDate = ave(endDate, memb, FUN = max))
```

giving:

```
  id  startDate    endDate overlap newStartDate newEndDate
1  1 1990-01-01 1990-01-24    TRUE   1990-01-01 1990-01-25
2  1 1990-01-23 1990-01-25    TRUE   1990-01-01 1990-01-25
3  1 1990-01-30 1990-01-31   FALSE   1990-01-30 1990-01-31
```

**3a)** Alternately we can form g from `nbrs` to avoid forming `adj` like this:

```
g0 <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(stack(nbrs)), directed = FALSE)
g <- simplify(g0) # remove self loops
```

### Graphics

As an aside using `g` we can display a graphical representation where node i means row i and edges indicate overlap.

```
plot(g)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a `data.table` - dependent function called `find_overlaps` like below:

```
library(data.table)

find_overlaps <- function(df, 
                          groups = NULL, 
                          start_var = NULL, 
                          end_var = NULL, 
                          fmt = "%Y-%m-%d") {

  calc_cummax_Date <- function(x) setattr(cummax(unclass(x)), "class", c("Date", "IDate"))

  df_overlap <- setDT(copy(df))

  rangevars <- c(start_var, end_var)
  groupsidx <- c(groups, "overlap_idx")

  df_overlap <- df_overlap[
    , (rangevars) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), format = fmt)), .SDcols = rangevars][
      , max_until_now := shift(calc_cummax_Date(get(end_var)), fill = get(end_var)[1]), by = mget(groups)][
        (max_until_now + 1L) < get(start_var), gap_between := 1][
          is.na(gap_between), gap_between := 0][
            , overlap_idx := cumsum(gap_between), by = mget(groups)][
              , `:=` (overlap = .N > 1,
                      newStartDate = min(get(start_var)),
                      newEndDate = max(get(end_var))), by = groupsidx][
                        , c("gap_between", "max_until_now") := NULL
                        ]

  return(df_overlap)

}
```

Calling this function (with `[]` at the end for printing the output) would give you the desired output:

```
# Below code will only print the output, you have to save it by e.g. df <- find_overlaps(df, groups = "id", start_var = "startDate", end_var = "endDate")

find_overlaps(df, groups = "id", start_var = "startDate", end_var = "endDate")[]

   id  startDate    endDate overlap_idx overlap newStartDate newEndDate
1:  1 1990-01-01 1990-01-24           0    TRUE   1990-01-01 1990-01-25
2:  1 1990-01-23 1990-01-25           0    TRUE   1990-01-01 1990-01-25
3:  1 1990-01-30 1990-01-31           1   FALSE   1990-01-30 1990-01-31
```

As you can see, I've also added a column named `overlap_idx` as I believe it may be useful to have a separate index for each non-overlapping range per each `id`.

The function can handle multiple groups. Since it checks for cumulative maximum in the end date variable it would work also with cases where a line has the lowest start date but also highest end date. Additional parameters (like `max_days_between`, i.e. the definition of what do you consider to be continuous - 1 day difference or more) can be added easily.

---

If you're interested, the above function is partly similar to a function called `collapse_ranges` from my package `neatRanges` (available on `CRAN`, but still in experimental state).

It would give you a collapsed output, similar to what you want but as a summary of only first and last start/end dates for each non-overlapping range:

```
install.packages('neatRanges')
library(neatRanges)

collapse_ranges(df, groups = "id", start_var = "startDate", end_var = "endDate")[]

  id  startDate    endDate
1  1 1990-01-01 1990-01-25
2  1 1990-01-30 1990-01-31
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution for a similar problem. As I needed to apply the same logic to a large dataset, my way to go was `Rcpp` and `data.table` (sorting speed reason really). Works also on multiple groups - ids. The `conti()` function produced the aggregated range of time periods without, in this case, a day of interruption (can be tuned with tolerance):

```
conti <- function(
  data = df, 
  group = "id", #the group variable by which to aggregate the dates
  dateFrom = "startDate",
  dateTo = "endDate",
  tolerance = 0, #what gap shall be seen as uninterupted range on dates, here 0 tollerance
  dateFormat = "%Y-%m-%d" #date format in df
  ) {
  if(!require(Rcpp)){install.packages("Rcpp"); library(Rcpp)}
  if(!require(data.table)){install.packages("data.table"); library(data.table)}
  cppFunction('DataFrame BezRcpp(DataFrame dtable) {
              int marker = 0;
              IntegerVector ID = dtable["group"];
              DateVector From = dtable["dateFrom"];
              DateVector To = dtable["dateTo"];
              IntegerVector Difference(ID.size(), 9999);

              for (int i = 1; i < ID.size(); i++) {
                if(ID[i] != ID[i-1]) {
                  marker = i;
                } else {
                  Difference[i] = From[i] - To[marker];
                  if(Difference[i]>1) marker = i;
                    else if(To[i]>To[marker]){
                      To[marker] = To[i];
              }}}
              return DataFrame::create(
                  _["group"] = ID,
                  _["Difference"] = Difference,
                  _["dateFrom"] = From,
                  _["dateTo"] = To,
                  _["stringsAsFactors"] = false);
            }'
  )
  conti_Rcpp_ <- function(data){
    A <- Sys.time()
    if(!"data.table" %in% class(data)) dtable <- as.data.table(data) else dtable <- copy(data)
    setnames(dtable, old = c("id", "startDate", "endDate"), new = c("group", "dateFrom", "dateTo"))
    if(class(dtable[["dateFrom"]])!="Date" || class(dtable[["dateTo"]])!="Date") for (j in c("dateFrom", "dateTo")) set(dtable, j = j, value = as.Date(dtable[[j]], dateFormat)) 
    setorderv(dtable, c("group", "dateFrom"))
    dt <- setDT(BezRcpp(dtable))
    dt <- dt[Difference>(tolerance+1), c("group", "dateFrom", "dateTo"), with = F]
    setnames(dt, new = c("id", "startDate", "endDate"), old = c("group", "dateFrom", "dateTo"))
    B <- Sys.time()
    print(paste0("Done in ", round(difftime(B, A, units = "secs"), 1), " secs. A data.table was produced."))
    return(dt)
  }
  return(conti_Rcpp_(data))
}
```

Then

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L),
                 startDate = c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-23", "1990-01-30"),
                 endDate = c("1990-01-24", "1990-01-25", "1990-01-31"), stringsAsFactors = F)

conti(df)
#[1] "Done in 0 secs. A data.table was produced."
#   id  startDate    endDate
#1:  1 1990-01-01 1990-01-25
#2:  1 1990-01-30 1990-01-31
```